# Keeping symbology properties when converting from CSV layer to shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, symbology, csv

Is it possible to keep specific symbology settings when converting from a CSV file to a shapefile in QGIS?

I've added categorised renderer settings within my CSV file layer and don't want to loose this.

I know this can be added again manually to the shapefile layer but I would like to avoid doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the symbology as a style file.

- open layer properties - symbology
- at the bottom select the 'style' drop-down menu and follow the prompts.